# Чем обусловлена запятая перед тире в следующих предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Столпившийся народ безмолвно слушал эти заклинания, — и перед его духовными очами возникали дни изгнания, бедствия и напасти прошедших времен (И. Тургенев).

Люди гораздо ниже Фауста воображали найти, наконец, блаженство в любви женщины гораздо выше Маргариты, — и вы сами знаете, читатель, каким аккордом разрешались все эти вариации (И. Тургенев).

Для исполнения своего назначения человек должен увеличивать в себе любовь и проявлять ее в мире, — и это увеличение любви и проявление ее в мире, есть то самое, что нужно... (Л. Толстой).

По свойству своему любовь, желание блага, стремится обнять все существующее. Естественным путем оно расширяет свои пределы любовью, — сначала к семейным — жене, детям, потом к друзьям (Л. Толстой).

И хлынул дождь, — вот он.

Был май, — славный, веселый май; свежая, ярко-зеленая листва, рожденная им, ликовала; шум ее лился широкой и звучной струей в лазурное, яркое небо, — а в нем тихо плавали белые пуховые облака и таяли в ярких лучах веселого солнца весны;

Чайки стонут перед бурей, — стонут, мечутся над морем и на дно его готовы спрятать ужас свой пред бурей. И гагары тоже стонут, — им, гагарам, недоступно наслажденье битвой жизни.

Есть ощущение, что это устаревшие правила русского языка, так как в справочниках я не могу найти обоснование подобной пунктуации.

Comment: Был май,— славный, веселый май. В этом предложении запятой перед тире быть не должно, так как запятая в подобных случаях допустима лишь в тех случаях, когда повторяющееся слово (май) следует сразу после тире.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенных примерах используется **запятая и тире как единый знак**.

Он обозначает авторское деление предложения на смысловые части, в устной речи делается пауза.

В современном правописании использование запятой и тире как единого знака, например в БСП, обычно регулируется правилами, то есть требуются дополнительные формальные признаки.

В правилах Лопатина этот знак  отнесен **к устаревающим** (в ССП при наличии авторской паузы используется тире).

ПАС http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Примечание. Между частями сложносочиненного предложения **может стоять запятая и тире как единый знак препинания**: Оскалив зубы, староста стал драть его кнутом по чем попало, — и от боли и от ужаса Аверкий проснулся весь в слезах (Бун.); На очереди были полицейские пункты, — и там о Давиде никто ничего не слыхал (Пришв.). **Такое разделение частей сложносочиненного предложения несколько устарело.**